# Need help translating from SQL to LINQ

Tags: .net, linq

I have the following SQL statement

```
select RegionBoundaryID, RegionBoundary.lat, RegionBoundary.long, RegionID
from RegionBoundary join Region_Boundary on RegionBoundary.RegionBoundaryID = Region_Boundary.BoundaryID
order by RegionID, RegionBoundaryID
```

Here is its translation to LINQ

```
 var context = new DataClassesRegionDataContext();
 var regionBoudaries = from boundaryID in context.Region_Boundaries
                       join boundariesDetail in context.RegionBoundaries on boundaryID.BoundaryID equals boundariesDetail.RegionBoundaryID
                       select new RegionViewModel { ID = boundariesDetail.RegionBoundaryID, Latitude = boundariesDetail.lat.Value, Longitude = boundariesDetail.@long.Value, RegionID = boundaryID.RegionID };
 regionBoudaries.OrderBy(region => region.RegionID).ThenBy(region => region.ID);
```

However, the result I got from LINQ is different from that of SQL statement. Where was I wrong in the LINQ statement? Thank you.

**Edit**: The difference is in the order which my results appear

Comment: What is different? Is the query different or the results?

Comment: The result you get are totally different or just in sorting?

Comment: Yes that is the difference :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should produce same query:

```
var context = new DataClassesRegionDataContext();
var regionBoudaries = from rb in context.Region_Boundaries
                      join b in context.RegionBoundaries 
                           on rb.BoundaryID equals b.RegionBoundaryID
                      orderby rb.RegionID, b.RegionBoundaryID // ordering here
                      select new RegionViewModel { 
                           ID = b.RegionBoundaryID, 
                           Latitude = b.lat.Value, // what if null?
                           Longitude = b.@long.Value, // what if null?
                           RegionID = rb.RegionID 
                      };
```

BTW table names and variable names are awful. Two tables which differs with underscore only! And name of variable boundaryID looks like some integer (or other identity type).

Comment: 1) Thank you for your idea about names of the table. 2) I have set the database to not to allow null in `lat` and `long`, is it adequate? Thanks again

Comment: @MinhTriet I pointed at `lat` and `long` because currently both are nullable values (i.e. in database Null was possible value). If both can't be null, then yes, make them required in database, and LINQ to SQL (or EF) will generate them as non-nullable also

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` *return* ordered enumerables, they do not *modify* the underlying enumerable, so you should be using:

```
var regionBoudaries = from boundaryID in context.Region_Boundaries
                       join boundariesDetail in context.RegionBoundaries on boundaryID.BoundaryID equals boundariesDetail.RegionBoundaryID
                       select new RegionViewModel { ID = boundariesDetail.RegionBoundaryID, Latitude = boundariesDetail.lat.Value, Longitude = boundariesDetail.@long.Value, RegionID = boundaryID.RegionID };
regionBoudaries = regionBoudaries.OrderBy(region => region.RegionID).ThenBy(region => region.ID);
```